# How can I find dependancies in my data in R? (A + B + C -> D)

Tags: r, correlation, r-caret

I want to reduce my data by sorting out dependent variables. E.g. `A + B + C -> D` so I can leave out D without loosing any information.

```
d <- data.frame(A = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                B = c( 2, 4, 6, 4, 2), 
                C = c( 3, 4, 2, 1, 0),
                D = c( 6, 10, 11, 9, 9))
```

The last value of D is wrong, that is because the data can be inaccurate.

How can I identify these dependencies with R and how can I influence the accuracy of the correlation? (e.g., use a cutoff of 80 or 90 percent)

Example `findCorrelation` only considers pair-wise correlations. Is there a function for multiple correlations?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify what you mean by multiple correlations (as opposed to pairwise correlations `cor(d)`)?

Comment: a correlation of A + B + C -> D or is that not called correlation?

Comment: So you want to calculate the correlation coefficient between a (*any*?) linear combination of `A`, `B`, `C` with `D`? Something like `cor(d$A + d$B + d$C, d$D)`?

Comment: jup, to calculate any possible correlations in a data frame, a + b or a + b + c ... c + d ...

Comment: Do you always have three columns `A`, `B`, `C` and a fourth column `D`? Why do you want to add them? Are they scaled to zero mean and unit variance? It sounds like an odd thing to do...

Comment: Jup, first I check for variance, then for pair-wise correlation. and now i want to find any other correlation in my data. Why? My real data has 200 columns and can't see the correlation by myself!

Comment: `A`, `B`, `C` are definitely *not* scaled. Also you say `A+B+C = D` (except for the last value); so obviously `cor(d$A +d$B + d$C, d$D)` will be close to 1. As far as I understand, adding un-scaled columns makes no sense.

Comment: I think you really want something more along the lines of what @Fer Arce shows. A linear model will give you the coefficients of columns `A`, `B` and `C` to give you response `D`.

Comment: Ok, the problem with @Fer Arce method is that he expects the correlation at D. I don't know where the correlation is! I want to find any correlation automatically since the real data is not 4 Columns but 200 Columns...

Comment: As I explain, adding (random) variables on different scales is not very meaningful for exploring correlations. To be honest I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and I'm even less sure that you want to be looking at correlations. Correlations measure the strength of association between two variables. While two correlated variables are also dependent, the converse is not necessarily true (two dependent variables can be uncorrelated). If I understand you correctly you want to model `D` as a function of all the other  variables/columns. You can address this in a linear model.

Comment: That is true if I know that A+B+C -> D. But in reality i don't know that because I have 200 Variables infront of me! So this is an example.... Scenario: You don't see any dependancies! You need to ceck all possible combinations. with 4 variables you can do this manually, with 200 you can't... So is there a possibility to check the data for dependancies/correlation or what so ever?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157567/discussion-between-dan-and-maurits-evers).

Comment: How about a linear model with ridge regression (e.g. `glmnet`) to take care of multicollinearity between the 200 variables. You will then get coefficients for those variables that explain `D`, whilst the remaining variables will be shrunk to zero. I definitely think linear modelling is the way to go here...

Comment: @Dan - have a look at the Ridge Regression and PCA from this doc - [Ridge Regression and PCA](http://personal.psu.edu/jol2/course/stat597e/notes2/lreg.pdfhttp://personal.psu.edu/jol2/course/stat597e/notes2/lreg.pdf)

Comment: There is `findLinearCombos` in `caret`.

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question. Its asking for recommendations on a statistical method to use. This should be on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ - but due to bounty can't vote to migrate it.

Comment: Well programming is the implementation of the statistical method, so for one i need the statistical method and after that the implementation. I don't see why there is such a big difference, since you should know what you implement....

Comment: @Dan A two-step process would have probably gone better.  Get the determination of method out of the way on stats.stackexchange.com and get implementation here.  Too bad stats.stackexchange.com moved away from statistical programming being in scope.

Comment: Do you want the correlation of individual predictors to the outcome (controlling for all other predictors) or do you want the correlation of the prediction to the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find dependencies in your data, you contrast `findCorrelation` with what you want asking 'is there a function for multiple correlations'.  To answer that we need to clarify the technique that is appropriate for you...

Do you want partial correlation:

> Partial correlation is the correlation of two variables while controlling for a third or more other variables

or semi-partial correlation?

> Semi-partial correlation is the correlation of two variables with variation from a third or more other variables removed only from the second variable.

Definitions from [{ppcor}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ppcor/ppcor.pdf). [Decent YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKRdp4qiCPs) although the speaker might have some of the relationship to regression details slightly confused/confusing.

To Fer Arce's suggestion... it is about right.  Regression is quite related to these methods, however when predictors are correlated (called multicollinearity) it can cause [issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32464/how-does-the-correlation-coefficient-differ-from-regression-slope) (see the answer by gung).  You could force your predictors to be orthogonal (uncorrelated) via PCA, but then you'd make interpreting the coefficients quite hard.

Implementation:

```
library(ppcor)
d <- data.frame(A = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                B = c( 2, 4, 6, 4, 2), 
                C = c( 3, 4, 2, 1, 0),
                D = c( 6, 10, 11, 9, 9))
# partial correlations
pcor(d, method = "pearson")
# semi-partial correlations
spcor(d, method = "pearson")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a 'correlation', if you fit a lm

```
summary(lm(D ~ A + B + C, data =d))
```

But I am not sure what are you exactly asking for. I mean, with this you can get R^2, that I guess is what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to find any dependencies in my data... so i have to look at all data. How do you know that D ~ A + B + C ? That is possible to see in smal data but not in a big data lake..

Comment: A, B, C and D are an example... The real data has 200 Columns... There I don't see the correlation by myself...

Comment: Well, I know that because it is the structure that you mentioned in your post.  Actually the multiple R-squared is like 0.95, and the adjusted is a bit lower, 0.8.

Comment: Then you need to think which of your columns are more relevant. Of course there are tools for 'dredging' and run hundreds of model combinations (it would be easy to code also) but I am not in this world so I cannot help you.

You should edit your post to make it more understandable, what you want is not what you aked for.

Answer (score 1):

Although correlation matrices are helpful and perfectly legitimate, one way I find particularly useful is to look at the variance inflation factor.  Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) describing the `VIF` is quite good.

A few reasons why I like to use the `VIF`:

1. Instead of looking at rows or columns of a correlation matrix, to try and divine which variables are more collinear than others with the other covariates multiply instead of singly, you get a single number which describes an aspect of a given predictor's relationship to all others in the model.
2. It's easy to use the `VIF` in a stepwise fashion to, in most cases, eliminate collinearity within your predictor space.
3. It's easy to obtain, either through using the `vif()` function in the `car` package, or by writing your own function to calculate.

`VIF` essentially works by regressing all the covariates/predictors in your model against each predictor you've included in turn.  It obtains the `R^2` value and takes the ratio: `1/(1-R^2)`.  This gives you a number `vif >= 1`.  If you think of `R^2` as the amount of variation in your response space explained by your selected covariate model, then if one of your covariates gets a high `R^2` of, say `0.80`, then your `vif` is `5`.

You choose what your threshold of comfort is.  The wikipedia article suggests a `vif` of `10` indicates a predictor should go.  I was taught that `5` is a good threshold.  Often, I've found it's easy to get the `vif` down to less than `2` for all of my predictors without a big impact to my final models `adjusted-R^2`.

I feel like even a `vif` of `5`, meaning a predictor can be modeled by its companion predictors with an `R^2` of `0.80` means that that predictors marginal information contribution is quite low and not worth it.  I try to take a strategy of minimizing all of my `vifs` for a given model without a huge (say, `> 0.1` reduction in `R^2`) impact to my main model.  That sort of an impact gives me a sense that even if the `vif` is higher than I'd like, the predictor still holds a lot of information.

There are other approaches.  You might look into [Lawson's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947301000561) on an alias-matrix-guided variable selection method as well - I feel it's particularly clever, though harder to implement than what I've discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

The Question is about how it is possible to detect dependancies in larger sets of data.
For one this is possible by manually checking every possibility, like proposed in other answers with `summary(lm(D ~ A + B + C, data =d))` for example. But this means a lot of manual work.

I see a few possibilities. For one Filter Methods like `RReliefF` or `Spearman Correlation` for example. they look at the correlation and
measure distance witin the data set.

Possibility two is using `Feature Extraction` methods lika `PCA`, `LDA` or `ICA` all trying to find the independent compontents (meaning eliminating any correlations...)

Comment: Feature Extraction won't give you predictions on D.  PCA can be used on the set of input features to extract an orthogonal set, but then you're still left with a similar issue.

Spearman correlation is a special case of Pearson correlation and seldom is what people mean when they just say 'correlation'.  Correlation unqualified is usually Pearson correlation.